# What is the best way to load alternate image when the main image does not load ( .net web forms)

Tags: javascript, .net, image

-File exist IO check. 
-Use javascript onerror function .
-Check for 404 response. if 404 display default image.

Which of these methods will load the page fastest?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where the files are located. If they are all in a local folder on the server, I would say use the File.Exists() method. This way you can perform a quick check if they exist and swap it with something else if it does not.

If the images are on a remote server, or even coming from a website, then you would probably need to deal with a JavaScript solution. This method might be a little slower for the user since the page would have to load and then perform its checks, and possibly even swap out the image.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to just show a clean "image not available" image then using Javascript is your best option.  Having the server hit the filesystem works, but is extra work for a minor presentation feature.